# $(window).load(function(){ is not working in iframe page in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have the below code in my iframe page.

```
 $(window).load(function() {
    // No we can paint our canvas. Something rounded with a shadow ;-)
    $("#main-outer").liquidCanvas(

        "[shadow gradient{from:#000000; to:#ffffff;}] => roundedRect{radius:10}");
  });
```

when the parent page loads, the code inside iframe page not works. 
When i run the iframe page individually it works fine.
I have this problem in IE only.

The problem is `$(window).load(function(){` is not working in iframe page. How to fix this?

This liquid canvas plugin works with $(window).load(function()) and not with other functions

Comment: Why are you using `$(window).load` in your iframe instead of using `$(document).ready`?

Comment: windows load event is way to soon, try to use document ready instead ... `$(document).ready( ... );`

Comment: @balexandre: *"windows load event is way to soon"* You mean too late.

Comment: @balexandre The `window` load event usually fires *after* the `document` ready event - `load` waits for resources like images to load, while ready only waits till the DOM is, well, ready

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're not the only one, there are a couple of comments on [the `load` function's API page](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) from people saying they have the same problem.

If you haven't already tried this, you might try a boring old-fashioned DOM0 event handler:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // No we can paint our canvas. Something rounded with a shadow ;-)
    $("#main-outer").liquidCanvas(
        "[shadow gradient{from:#000000; to:#ffffff;}] => roundedRect{radius:10}"
    );
};
```

...in case IE has some issue with its DOM2 mechanism. (They are somewhat separate mechanisms for various reasons.)